# How do you enable and configure syslog server in OSX server 10.6?

Tags: mac-osx-server, syslog

I am completely new to OSX server.  How do I turn on the syslog service?  I also need it to accept connections from remote network switches.

This seems to [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/131578/how-do-you-enable-syslogd-to-accept-incoming-connections-on-snow-leopard-from-rem) the second part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this article here: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060327074531639

It is specifically for 10.4 but if I remember correctly, it applies to the current 10.6 configuration.

I haven't had to setup syslogd on a mac in a while but the steps described seem very familiar. I also don't have an OSX server to test on right now.